# CD-R drive is not working

Tags: cd-drive

I have a Power Spec (Micro Center, Columbus, Ohio house brand) computer in which the CD-R drive has stopped working. When I insert a CD, I do not hear the drive starting, nor do I see any results on my screen. The drive was working well until a few days ago.

My computer's processor is an `Intel Pentium 4`, `2.23GHz` clock speed, 1GB RAM.

Am I being denied access to the drive, and if so, how do I reset the access permissions?

Comment: Firstly you should rule out possible hardware issues, such as cable connection failures; sometimes  just disconnecting and reconnecting cables does wonders. Turn off the machine first though.